# Why is Visual Studio not stepping into my assignment operators?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I'm trying to get a firm grasp on move and copy constructors and assignments.

I have the following simple templated class:

```
template<typename T>
class Box {

public:
    // Copy constructor
    explicit Box(const T& val) { 
        value = val; 
    }

    // Move constructor
    explicit Box(const T&& val) {
        value = val;
    }

    // Set and get value
    void set(T val) { value = val; }
    T get() { return value; }

    // Copy assignment operator
    T& operator=(const T& val) {
        value = val;
    }

    // Move assignment operator
    T& operator=(const T&& val) {
        value = val;
    }

private:
    T value;

};
```

Which is used by the following code:

```
int main() {
    Box<int> iBox{ 1 };

    int j = 5;
    Box<int> jBox{ j };

    iBox = jBox;

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect, if my code is correct, that when I step into `iBox = jBox`, I should step into one of the assignment overloads. Why is this not happening?

Comment: Look for Enable "Just My Code" in the debug options. Alternatively, disable optimizations

Comment: Did you disable inlining for debugging? If not, the function might not be called, but executed in place.

Comment: @sehe, `Tools|Options|Debugging|General|Enable Just My Code` has no effect. @king_nak, `Project Properties|C/C++|Optimizations|Inline Function Expansion` has no effect (assuming I'm fiddling with the right option...) and optimizations are already off (in the same place).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not declared an assignment operator taking a right-hand operand of type `Box`, so the compiler has no other option than to use its generated default assignment operator.

You also have no `return` statements in your assignment operators, by the way.

Maybe you meant to write:

```
Box& operator=(const Box& other) {
    value = other.value;
    return *this;
}

Box& operator=(Box&& val) {
    value = other.value;
    return *this;
}
```

Notice that an rvalue reference to `const` would make little sense.

Comment: Yep, I just noticed this defect in my code. The operators should have `Box` instead of `T` for the types...